# Склонения слова "перец"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, — возник вопрос по поводу употребления слова "перец" в родительном падеже — "перца".

`Девушка отправила в магазин, написала список — купить: хлеба, колбасы, молока, перца и т. д. Я купил всë перечисленное, а так же купил приправу, молотый перец, на что она ответила: "Это очевидно — я имела в виду купить не приправу, а овощи". На мой ответ, что нельзя использовать слово "перца", когда речь идет об овощах,  так, как это сделала она, сказала, что я недалекий.`

Comment: Ты - нормальный, но лучше "перца". Купить: хлеб молоко перец/ хлеба, молока, перца. Если перец - приправа, то перцу. Ну можно сказать перцев, если уж совсем тяжко.

Comment: Существительное, неодушевлённое, мужской род, 2-е склонение (тип склонения 5*a по классификации А. А. Зализняка). В знач. ‘парень’ слово склоняется по образцу для одушевлённых существительных (кого/что? — перца, перцев). Перцев - получится парней... хотя сейчас и для растений говорят перцев. Короче, я бы говорил перца, а если же кусты-растения или парни - перцев, если же приправа - перцу. И, обзываться не хорошо, если девушка такая культурная и грамотная, то это тоже не мешало бы знать.

Comment: Если в записке было "два кГ перца", - то между падежами уже не спрятаться...

Comment: "Также" нужно слитно написать.

Answer (score 0):

Перец в родительном падеже это **пе́рца в ед.ч. и во множественном пе́рцев** и когда говорят о овощах говорят **(Кого? Чего?) перца перцев** в зависимости от случая. И если говорят о блюдах говорят блюда из перца
**Спряжение**
(Кто? Что?) перец перцы
(Кого? Чего?) перца перцев
(Кому? Чему?) перцу перцам
(Кого? Что?) перец перцы
(Кем? Чем?) перцем перцами
(О ком? О чем?) перце перцах

Comment: «Перец в родительном падеже это пе́рца в ед.ч.» — Вот не надо тут))) «Чтоб уха была по сердцу // Можно будет в кипяток // Положить немного ПЕРЦУ, // Луку маленький кусок...»